# How can i forward to LUIS Dialog from Base Luis Dialog

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have implemented a simple work flow using LUIS BOT framework
Now i created a new LUIS Dialog to carry the sub flow of main Dialog. Basically, I want to enable LUIS intent action on the conversational flow

I defined LUIS Intent for the sub Luis Dialog too, but unfortunately, it is not even hitting the SubLUIS dialog and return back to the Root dialog. Am i missing anything?

Here is my Sample code,

**MAIN LUIS DIALOG:**

```
 public virtual async Task PaymentConfirmationReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result; // We've got a message!
        // User said 'order', so invoke the New Order Dialog and wait for it to finish.
            // Then, call ResumeAfterNewOrderDialog.
            // await context.Forward(new OrderDialog(), this.ResumeAfterNewOrderDialog, message, CancellationToken.None);

          await context.Forward(
          new OrderDialog(),
           ResumeAfterNewOrderDialog,
          result,
          CancellationToken.None);

        // User typed something else; for simplicity, ignore this input and wait for the next message.
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }


private async Task ResumeAfterNewOrderDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        // Store the value that NewOrderDialog returned. 
        // (At this point, new order dialog has finished and returned some value to use within the root dialog.)
        var resultFromNewOrder = await result;
        await context.PostAsync($"New order dialog just told me this: {resultFromNewOrder}");
         // Again, wait for the next message from the user.
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }
```

**SUB LUIS DIALOG**

```
 [LuisIntent(Intent_Go)]
    public async Task ProcessGo(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            // var sentiment = await TextAnalyticsService.DetermineSentimentAsync(sentence);
            string entities = this.BotEntityRecognition(Intent_PaymentGo, result);
            // round number
            var roundedScore = result.Intents[0].Score != null ? (Math.Round(result.Intents[0].Score.Value, 2)) : 0;
            if (roundedScore > 8)
            {
                ---do some operations---
                await context.PostAsync(data.ToString());
                context.Wait(MessageReceived);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Ok Fine! Let us know if we can help with any other queries!");
                context.Wait(MessageReceived);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add more details of your implementation of your dialogs: which file contains which "Dialog" here, and all the dialogs implementation. Currently it's unsolvable

Comment: If this is for one LUIS application, I'm not sure I see the necessity of having more than one LUIS Dialog. Practically speaking, it would be easier (and maybe better) to route from a LUIS Dialog to a regular Dialog. LUIS Dialogs exist to as a way to handily route to a dialog based on an intent. At face value it sounds like you want to route from one intent to another intent (from LUIS Dialog to LUIS dialog), but it's not clear as to why you to do this based on the question or your code. Are the users answering questions inside your root LUIS Dialog and then being routed?